# Retrieving month from a date using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have this simple code below for extracting a month from a date ..The issue is it returns just single digit month like 5 or 6 but I want it to return 05 or 06 .Is there any easy way to do it.

```
Dim date 
date = DateAdd("m",-1,Date)
WScript.Echo Month(date)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Canonical way to pad numeric month values with a leading zero:

```
d = DateAdd("m", -1, Date)
WScript.Echo Right("0" & Month(d), 2)
```

BTW, you shouldn't use a variable `date` as the name conflicts with the built-in function `Date`. VBScript doesn't distinguish between upper and lower case in variable/function names.